# How to display an image in windows forms from a different device

Tags: c#, image, winforms, button, path

Alright, so I'm looking for a more or less quick fix for an issue... On a program I've built, The image on a button is changed when a KeyDown event occurs. Initially, I changed the image by saying `button1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"......");`
The problem is that when I put the program on a USB, the new computer looks for the file on the same pathway and can't find it, creating an error. The only images that load are the ones that are used in the designer area, the ones the buttons start with. So because of that, I made a whole pile of extra buttons, assigned them my needed images, hid them all using `Button3.Hide();` . I changed all the `button1.Image = Image.FromFile(@"...")` to `Button1.Image = Button2.Image`and then put it on the stick to try again.
As you may have guessed, it did not work. Any advice on how to make the images work on all computers?

Comment: Why are you hiding the path from us in your question?  It's not a secret.  If you are doing something like `Image.FromFile(@"x:\funky\folder\images\incoming stuff\wednesday")` and that path doesn't exist on your device then that's the problem.  Images should either be a WinForms Resource; or deployed relative to your app.  Ensure your paths are always relative and not absolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bundle the images as **part of your executable file** by making them an **Embedded Resource**.

1. Click on Project --> Properties.
2. One the Left, Select "Resources".
3. Now across the Top, click the DropDown Arrow next to "Add Resource"
       and Select "Add Existing File".
4. Navigate to the first Image File and
       Double Click it.
5. In the Properties Pane for the Image (bottom right
       by default) change the "Persistence" to "Embedded in.resx".

Repeat steps #3 to #5 for the second Image file.

Now go back to design mode for your Form and select your Button.  Click the three dots "..." next to the Image property and you should now see the two Images listed in the bottom half under the "Project resource file:" area.  Select the default image from there.

When the KeyDown() event occurs, you can use code like this to change the Image:

```
button1.Image = Properties.Resources.sv_privilege;
```

where "sv_privilege" is the name of the resource you embedded earlier and want to switch to.